# Grails AWS SDK plugin not resolving PutObjectRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to get my grails app working with Amazon S3, I have been following the following docs... http://agorapulse.github.io/grails-aws-sdk/guide/single.html

At the following step `amazonWebService.s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest('some-grails-bucket', 'somePath/someKey.jpg', new File('/Users/ben/Desktop/photo.jpg')).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead))`

The project can't resolve class `PutObjectRequest`, and I have tried importing `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest` manually, but it still cant find the class.  The only thing I can think of is I might have an older version of the SDK, though I only followed the tutorial.

My `BuildConfig.groovy`...

```
...
dependencies{
   //dependencies for amazon aws plugin
   build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
   build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'
   runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
   runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.2'
}
plugins{
   ...
   runtime ':aws-sdk:1.9.40'
}
```

has anyone else run into this issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the plugin, I simply just use the SDK directly. Not sure what you would need a plugin for. You don't need httpcomponents for it to work

Add this to you dependencies block:

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'
}
```

Heres my bean I use. I set the key, access, and bucket data in the bean configuration

```
class AmazonStorageService implements FileStorageService {


    String accessKeyId
    String secretAccessKey
    String bucketName

    AmazonS3Client s3client

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey));
    }

    String upload(String name, InputStream inputStream) {
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, name, inputStream, null).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        getUrl(name)
    }

    String upload(String name, byte[] data) {
        upload(name, new ByteArrayInputStream(data))
    }

    String getUrl(String name) {
        s3client.getUrl(bucketName, name)
    }

    Boolean exists(String name) {
        try {
            s3client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, name)
            true
        } catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            false
        }
    }

}
```